# Error in owin startup class visual studio 2012 and also for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, katana

I created a project using vs 2012 asp .net web site.
But it is giving me error for all components of `Owin`,`Katana` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`. 

Its giving error :-

```
The type or namespace name 'Owin' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  ...@#$@\!#@$\Startup.cs
```

For Microsoft.AspNet.Identity its giving :-

```
The type or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   ~\Account\Manage.aspx.cs
```

Comment: It looks like I have to manually remove owin and katana and reinstall using nuget packages.